# Resharper extend selection and shrink selection

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I can't believe I'm asking this. I have resharper 9.0 and visual studio 2013 community. My extend selection hotkey is supposed to be ctrl alt right but that doesn't work at all. I can use ctrl-w  instead but ctrl-shift-w does not work for shrinking. I'd like to remap the bindings but I cant even find the resharper extend selection mapping in my keyboard options. I am able to find the shrink option and it's set to ctrl-alt-left (doesn't work). Tried changing it to alt-shift-down but STILL doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extend selection command is `ReSharper.ReSharper_SelectEmbracingConstruct`, and the shrink selection is `ReSharper.ReSharper_ShrinkSelection` (Yay consistency!) You can remap them in the Tools → Options → Keyboard dialog.

Or, you can reset keyboard shortcuts to default ReSharper settings by going to Tools → Options → Keyboard and hitting reset, then going to ReSharper → Options → Keyboard & Menus and hitting "Apply Scheme".

Comment: Note: extend has always been `ReSharper.ReSharper_ExtendSelection` - which matches the `ReSharper.ReSharper_ShinkSelection`.   SelectEmbracingConstruct is something similar, but different.